# SublimeText 2 - Save/Restore Session

Tags: sublimetext2

I am new to using sublime text and find it great. I am using Sublime in Ubuntu 12.04 and am missing some features.

In SublimeText if I open a Window and close it through the menu, next time I open SublimText, the Window with the open documents will be available. Great but not very useful, because I work with many projects simultaneously.I currently keep all of them open in many windows, but is a pain to do so.

I would like to store session information on a per folder/prject basis. So, when I open Sublime through the terminal, the session will be available

For example

```
$ cd /path/to/project
$ sublime-text .
# if a session is saved (project opened before), opens the Sublime with the last saved session for the folder/project
```

It will be great to know if it is possible. After days of searching, I have grown tired of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can open a project from the command line by passing the `.sublime-project` file as an argument. Within your project, you can put custom settings like `"remember_open_files": true`, but set it to `false` in your `Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got some advice from my supervisor which was quite close for this. Any ways thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, the remember + _reopen_ feature is still very fragile and counter-intuitive (if not broken): I've just freshly created a new project for a try; saved it (with its implicit workspace file), closed ST, then reopened, passing it the prj file. It worked fine, ONCE. After some editing, file opening, closing ST etc., and then renaming the project + the worksp. files (keeping them matching), it never again reopened anything. Not even after undoing the rename, or just deleting + recreating the ws (and then even after the prj!) file. (ST3, latest here.)

Comment: (FYI, an explicit "Save Workspace As" to force-update a previous one, and then a (most likely redundant) "Save All" before closing ST didn't help either. I do have `"remember_open_files": true` in the prj file, and disabled on the user-level, as suggested.)

Comment: I really dont know why this feature have to be so complicated. Its so frustating dont have some "remember last oppened files" by default.

Answer (score 1):

**To create session in sublime text**

Menu “Projects” -> “Save Workspace As…”     [Give name and save the session in a folder] [G:\General\Sublime]
Example File name
G:\General\Sublime\Corey10122020.sublime-workspace

Close the project after your project is over. The files in the project will be automatically update when close and open files in Sublime editor

***Open the session***

Menu “Projects”->Open Project..  [Select the file]
Example File name
G:\General\Sublime\Corey10122020.sublime-workspace